# hit.getDistance() not giving proper distance

Tags: arcore

I am looking to measure the height of a HitPose in `ARcore` and I am finding that the function `getDistance` sometimes returns what seems to be the wrong value for planes. 
Any thoughts on why this is or how to know how `getDistance` is calculating it's value?

I am using the handleTap function in the `HelloArActivity.java`(https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk) to demonstrate this.

I added the following function to dump the hit results of a hit test and call it in handleTap. Sample output shows the distance is intermittently way off yet calculating the distance but the sample function calculateDistanceToPlane shows the correct distance. Sample output follows code

```java
private String DumpHitList(List<HitResult> hitResultList, Frame frame){
    String str = new String();
    double angle[] = getAngleofthedevice();
    int index = 0;


    str = ".......Hit list size:"+hitResultList.size()+"..";

    for (HitResult hit : hitResultList){
        Trackable trackable = hit.getTrackable();
        // stuff to dump

        str += "\n[hit"+index++ +":";
        if (trackable instanceof Plane){
            str += "PLANE," + ((Plane) trackable).getType().toString()
                    +",inPolyGon:"+((Plane) trackable).isPoseInPolygon(hit.getHitPose())
                    +",normdist:" + PlaneRenderer.calculateDistanceToPlane(hit.getHitPose(), frame.getCamera().getPose())
            ;
        }
        else if (trackable instanceof Point) {
            str += "POINT," +((Point) trackable).getOrientationMode()
                    +",adjDist:"+ hit.getDistance()
                                  * (float)( Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle[1])) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle[2])))
            ;
        }
        else{
            str+= "OTHER TRACKABLE TYPE";
        }

        str += " trackDist:" + hit.getDistance() + " state:" + hit.getTrackable().getTrackingState();
        //str += ",hitXYZ:" + hit.getHitPose().tx() +","+hit.getHitPose().ty() +","+hit.getHitPose().tz()
        str += "\nhitPose:" + hit.getHitPose().toString();
        str += ",\ncamPose:" + frame.getCamera().getPose().toString()
        +"]\n ";

    }
    str +="........";


    return str;

}
```

Sample output (note the "trackdist" is way off from the norm distance).

```
2020-01-27 14:43:16.285 23970-24023/? D/Ahab: in create colored anchor plane:HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING hit dist:0.13333696, anchorDist: 0.23327702, hitlist size:1.......Hit list size:1..
    [hit0:PLANE,HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING,inPolyGon:true,normdist:0.23327702 trackDist:0.13333696 state:TRACKING
    hitPose:t:[x:0.167, y:-0.783, z:-0.821], q:[x:0.00, y:-0.59, z:-0.00, w:0.81],
    camPose:t:[x:0.161, y:-0.549, z:-0.819], q:[x:0.43, y:0.56, z:0.56, w:-0.44]]
     ........
2020-01-27 14:43:21.326 23970-24023/? D/Ahab: in create colored anchor pt:ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL hit dist:0.2452918, anchorDist: 0.24518394, hitlist size:2.......Hit list size:2..
    [hit0:POINT,ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL,adjDist:0.24518394 trackDist:0.2452918 state:TRACKING
    hitPose:t:[x:-0.091, y:-0.792, z:-0.789], q:[x:0.00, y:0.62, z:0.01, w:0.78],
    camPose:t:[x:-0.095, y:-0.547, z:-0.789], q:[x:0.53, y:0.46, z:0.46, w:-0.54]]

    [hit1:PLANE,HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING,inPolyGon:true,normdist:0.2366659 trackDist:0.13668406 state:TRACKING
    hitPose:t:[x:-0.091, y:-0.783, z:-0.789], q:[x:0.00, y:-0.64, z:-0.00, w:0.77],
    camPose:t:[x:-0.095, y:-0.547, z:-0.789], q:[x:0.53, y:0.46, z:0.46, w:-0.54]]

=====more sample output notice in one dump, "trackdist" is accurate but next dump, it is wrong. 
2020-01-27 14:43:16.285 23970-24023/? D/Ahab: in create colored anchor plane:HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING hit dist:0.13333696, anchorDist: 0.23327702, hitlist size:1.......Hit list size:1..
    [hit0:PLANE,HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING,inPolyGon:true,normdist:0.23327702 trackDist:0.13333696 state:TRACKING
    hitPose:t:[x:0.167, y:-0.783, z:-0.821], q:[x:0.00, y:-0.59, z:-0.00, w:0.81],
    camPose:t:[x:0.161, y:-0.549, z:-0.819], q:[x:0.43, y:0.56, z:0.56, w:-0.44]]
     ........
2020-01-27 14:43:21.326 23970-24023/? D/Ahab: in create colored anchor pt:ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL hit dist:0.2452918, anchorDist: 0.24518394, hitlist size:2.......Hit list size:2..
    [hit0:POINT,ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL,adjDist:0.24518394 trackDist:0.2452918 state:TRACKING
    hitPose:t:[x:-0.091, y:-0.792, z:-0.789], q:[x:0.00, y:0.62, z:0.01, w:0.78],
    camPose:t:[x:-0.095, y:-0.547, z:-0.789], q:[x:0.53, y:0.46, z:0.46, w:-0.54]]

    [hit1:PLANE,HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING,inPolyGon:true,normdist:0.2366659 trackDist:0.13668406 state:TRACKING
    hitPose:t:[x:-0.091, y:-0.783, z:-0.789], q:[x:0.00, y:-0.64, z:-0.00, w:0.77],
    camPose:t:[x:-0.095, y:-0.547, z:-0.789], q:[x:0.53, y:0.46, z:0.46, w:-0.54]]
```